# Changing language by clicking a button

Tags: jsf, internationalization, richfaces

I have a JSF/RichFaces setup, and I found this [tutorial](http://jsflessons.blogspot.com/p/internationalization.html). I followed it step by step, but I can't manage to get it.

Also: language.jsp is mentioned in the tutorial, can anybody tell me what exaclty it is?

Or if you think this is not an appropiate tutorial and have a better one, please, let me know.

Comment: Kanguage... Should be language...

Comment: I don't think I have better, but to some extent it is not appropriate. Your application should auto-detect browser language and adjust to it. Also recognizing lang attribute in URL's (i.e. http://example.com/index.html?lang=de) would be nice feature. Maybe you should just Google around the specific problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic locale switching in a JSF app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858868/dynamic-locale-switching-in-a-jsf-app)

Comment: browser based locale distinction is suboptimal because: 1) it is not fool proof and inconsistent for many reasons (different browsers provide info in "Accept-Language" header in a different way)   2) a user might be switching between different languages within the same region (for e.g. en_US and es_US)    3) all this means is that you are at the mercy of user to use browser specific way of changing the locale....u should use application specific way of locale switch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the steps in the tutorial are not really needed.
What I did (And it works) is:
1. In **loging.xhtm**, for instance:

```
    <f:view locale="#{languageDetails.locale}" >
    <head>
    .....
    <f:loadBundle basename="messages.Messages" var="msg1"/>
    .....
<f:view>
     <h:form>
          <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Select Language"></h:outputText>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="dropdown" value="#{languageDetails.locale}">
                      <f:selectItem itemValue="en" itemLabel="English" />
                      <f:selectItem itemValue="es" itemLabel="Spanish" />
                      <f:selectItem itemValue="de" itemLabel="German" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
          </h:panelGrid>
          <p><h:commandButton id="change" value="Change Language"
           action="#{languageDetails.changeLanguage}" /></p>


      </h:form>
</f:view>


    </body>
    </f:view>
```

2.In java source code I also made some changes:

```
public class LanguageDetails {

    private static String locale = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();

      public void setLocale(String locale1) {
        this.locale = locale1;
      }

      public synchronized String getLocale() {
        return locale;
      }

      public synchronized String changeLanguage() {
        return "changed";
      }
}
```

And that's all.
Hope this could help

Comment: Why are you using  synchronized?

Comment: Still waiting for an answer

Comment: Sorry @alexander, I had overseen your question. I don't really remember why I have the synchronized methods and I am not working on that application anymore. Obviously depending on the current application every developer is working on, this might be needed or not. But it doesn't interfere with the question.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to implement it as a button, which when I click on, the language changes. I have 2 locales (en, cs). Here's my solution:

1.command button:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton id="change" value="#{locale.locale}" action="#{locale.changeLanguage}" />
</h:form>
```

2.locale bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "locale")
@SessionScoped
public class LocaleBean {

private static String locale = "en";

  public void setLocale(String locale1) {
    LocaleBean.locale = locale1;
  }

  public synchronized String getLocale() {
    return locale;
  }

  public synchronized String changeLanguage() {
    if (!locale.contains("cs")) {
        setLocale("cs");
    } else {
        setLocale("en");
    }
      return "changed";
  }
}
```

Maybe this could be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

In the [JSF tutorial](http://jsflessons.blogspot.com/p/internationalization.html), language.jsp is a webpage which allow the user to select the locale of their choice.  In the example, language.jsp page is not internationalized. When you select a language from the drop down and click change language button, the next pages (which are internationalized)will be shown in the selected language. As clearly mentioned in the tutorial since the 'locale' attribute in f:view tag supports EL we can include 
<f:view locale="#{languageDetails.locale}"> in the next pages(UserDetailsForm.jsp and userDetailsSubmitted.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

You can change it by this code in bean, controller, etc...

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach **If you are using Spring**, is to declare these beans and call URL with parameter "locale=xx" to change locale:

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="es" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JSF you can use

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

but, sometimes you need to send some messages in specific users using them languages of registration then you need to user this

```
messages.getLocale().setDefault(
            new Locale(comm.getAccount().getLocale()));
```