# Problem changing language application

Tags: java, jsf, internationalization

as I asked time ago in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031944/changing-language-by-clicking-a-button), I solved my problem using this method:

1. In **loging.xhtm**, for instance:

   ```
   <f:view locale="#{languageDetails.locale}" >
   <head>
   .....
   <f:loadBundle basename="messages.Messages" var="msg1"/>
   .....
   ```

   ```
     </h:form>
   ```

   ```
   </body>
   </f:view>
   ```

2.In java source code I also made some changes:

```
public class LanguageDetails {

    private static String locale = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();

      public void setLocale(String locale1) {
        this.locale = locale1;
      }

      public synchronized String getLocale() {
        return locale;
      }

      public synchronized String changeLanguage() {
        return "changed";
      }
}
```

But now I'm trying to have the same option, not just in Login page, but in other pages.
Adding the same code in other pages, doesn't work, because function `setLocale` is not called. Any help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized, it's really important to put

```
<f:view locale="#{languageDetails.locale}" >
....
</f:view>
```

Or in every single file, or just in top file. Later, put `<h:selectOneMenu>` where necessary, but having always in mind that you can not have all `<h:form>` , `<a4j:form>`... etc. you want, it makes things more complicated. I put this **form tags** just on top files, and now everything is ok.
Hope this could help somebody.